# Raster clipping from many polygons: 'error: NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, gdal, fiona

I am using the following code to first divide a vector layer to many polygons and after that use them to clipping parts of a raster layer. The `Name` attribute in the vector data has a `text data type`. I am not sure why I receive the error of `'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Can anyone help me to solve this error?

```
import glob
import gdal
import fiona

with fiona.open('E:/data/vector.shp', 'r') as dst_in:
    for index, feature in enumerate(dst_in):
        with fiona.open('E:/data/polygons/NO_{}.shp'.format(index), 'w', **dst_in.meta) as dst_out:
            dst_out.write(feature)

polygons = glob.glob('E:/data/polygons/*.shp')  ## Retrieve all the .shp files

for polygon in polygons:
    feat = fiona.open(polygon, 'r')
    name = feat['properties']['Name']  
    command = 'gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -cutline {} ' \
              '-crop_to_cutline -of GTiff E:/data/raster.tif E:/data/outputraster/NO_{}.tif'.format(polygon, name)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ad6d7471adf6> in <module>
      1 for polygon in polygons:
      2     feat = fiona.open(polygon, 'r')
----> 3     name = feat['properties']['Name']
      4     command = 'gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -cutline {} ' \
      5               '-crop_to_cutline -of GTiff E:/data/raster.tif E:/data/outputraster/NO_{}.tif'.format(polygon, name)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: It looks like `feat` is returning `None`. Is `fiona.open()` working as you expect? You can open Shapefiles directly with fiona, rather than converting to `glob` first, perhaps that will be more reliable.

Comment: I tried to update the code using your comment, but not sure how to use fiona rather than using glob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`polygons` in your script are not polygons/features. They are shapefiles. `fiona.open` returns an opened `Collection` object. That means `feat` in your code is not a feature, it is a feature collection. You must iterate over the collection to get features.

Use like this:

```
shapefiles = glob.glob('E:/data/polygons/*.shp')

for shapefile in shapefiles:
    features = fiona.open(shapefile, 'r')
    for feat in features:
         name = feat['properties']['Name']
         ...
         ...
```

Comment: I updated the code based on your answer. When I run the code it does not output anything and also it shows no error.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the code running the following line should be added under 'command' in your script:

```
Popen(command, shell=True)
```